# How do i get the array beginning instead the end of it?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code in `timer1` tick event:

```
file_indxs = file_indxs - 1;
if (file_indxs < 0)
{
    file_indxs = file_array.Length - 1;
}
```

`file_array.Length - 1` is the end it will beging from the end of the array the last file in the array.

But i want to do :

```
file_indxs = file_indxs + 1;
if (file_indxs == 0)
{
    file_indxs = the beginning of the array. not the Length - 1
}
```

Comment: Arrays always start with index 0.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If `file_indxs == 0` is true, that variable *already contains* the first index in the array. Is there a chance the first `n` indices of the array may be *empty*, and you want to get the *first non-empty index*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want this

```
file_indxs = file_indxs + 1;
if (file_indxs >= file_array.Length)
{
    file_indxs = 0;
}
```

Meaning, when your index reaches the last element in the array restart from zero.... (used >= for safety)

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you *actually* want:

```
fileIndex++;
if (fileIndex == fileArray.Length)
{
    fileIndex = 0;
}
```

(I've changed the variable names to be more conventional at the same time.)

Note the change of condition - if you're *incrementing* `fileIndex`, you want to know when you've got to the end, not the beginning.